# Do frozen Lima Beans contain Cyanide?

Tags: food-safety, beans, frozen

I often buy frozen vegetables, defrost and eat them.

Recently, I came across an article that says [Lima Beans contain Cyanide](http://www.mnn.com/food/healthy-eating/photos/8-poisonous-foods-we-commonly-eat/1-lima-beans), should be thoroughly cooked and then eaten.

Do frozen Lima Beans come precooked or are they supposed to be cooked before consuming them?

---

*Location: Canada
If you need product information, please do let me know.*

Comment: Apples contain cyanide, too.  Of course, it's in the seeds.  (but lots of apple juice has it, because of how they extract the juice)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Raw lima beans do contain a compound, a cyanogenic glycoside, which would release cyanide if ingested raw.

(1) http://www.atsdr.cdc.gov/toxprofiles/tp8-c1.pdf

(2) http://www.foodsafety.govt.nz/elibrary/industry/Cyanogenic_Glycosides-Toxin_Which.pdf

(3) http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/24863488

(4) http://article.sciencepublishinggroup.com/pdf/10.11648.j.jfns.20140204.21.pdf

*Frozen lima beans are typically uncooked. The usual stories about cooking many varieties of lima beans quote boiling for at least 15 minutes and discarding the cooking water.*

---

***Now trying to unwind the folklore....***

**(A) What is the toxicity of cyanide?**

Cyanide in the body is an anion, which has a negative charge. In order to balance the charge a cation, a positive charged ion must be present too. Since beans would be eaten let's look at the toxicity of sodium cyanide.

The dose of [sodium cyanide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sodium_cyanide) which would kill 50% of the subjects (LD-50) is about 15 mg/kg of body weight for mammals. But by weight sodium cyanide is 47% sodium and 53% cyanide. So the lethal dose for cyanide itself would be about 7mg/kg.

So a 154 pound person weighs 70 kg (2.2 lbs per kg). 70*7 is approximately 500 mg or 0.5 grams.

**(B) Does the cyanide content of lima beans vary?**

Yes. Supposedly the varieties of lima beans consumed in the US (and presumably Canada) are specifically chosen to be low in cyanide.

Cyanide in "lima  beans [varies]  between  15  and  500  mg  HCN/kg  fresh  weight  (Bickerstaff,  2003)" quoted from:

(5) http://members.ecetoc.org/Documents/Document/JACC%20053%20Vol%20I.pdf

But I can find the original source by Bickerstaff in the article.

**(C) How much does cooking reduce the cyanide?**

There is a paper which notes that in other foods the cyanogenic glycosides are 100% destroyed by cooking.

(6) http://www.onlineresearchjournals.org/JBFSR/pdf/2013/jan/Onyeike%20et%20al..pdf

**(D) How does the bean produce cyanide?**

The cyanide in lima beans is present as "pure" cyanide, but a cyanide compound called a cyanogenic glycoside. Lima beans contain two such compounds, [linamarin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linamarin) and [lotaustralin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lotaustralin)

> > Linamarin
> >
> > [image]
> >
> > Lotaustralin
> >
> > [image]

I'll quote Dr. G. Speijers of the National Institute of Public Health and Environmental Protection, Laboratory for Toxicology, Bilthoven, The Netherlands

(7) http://www.inchem.org/documents/jecfa/jecmono/v30je18.htm

> > *The first aspect is the processing of plant products containing
> >     cyanogenic glycosides. When the edible parts of the plants are
> >     macerated, the catabolic intracellular enzyme ß-glucosidase can be
> >     released, coming into contact with the glycosides. This enzyme
> >     hydrolyzes the cyanogenic glycosides to produce hydrogen cyanide and
> >     glucose and ketones or benzaldehyde.*

It seems that the human gut also has bacteria which are capable of hydrolyzing the cyanogenic glycosides to produce hydrogen cyanide.

Comment: For reference, the bag in my freezer says to boil 12-15 minutes ("until tender") but says you can steam them just 6-8 minutes, so even the manufacturers seem to be a bit fuzzy about exactly how much cooking is necessary.

Comment: I like southern cooking. I cook them until soft, drain off water and mash a few to make sort of a sauce with a bit of water. Add butter, some salt and black pepper.

Comment: @Jefromi Yes, you're right. The bag in my freezer says the same.

Answer (score 0):

Lima beans contains Cyanide in small quantity [1].

I am not certain, nor do I want to make an uneducated guess as what quantity per/day/year one needs to eat in order to be sick (fatally or not)

They need to be cooked to let the cyanide evaporate as a gas; so cook'em up.

[...]Cooking the beans uncovered allows the poison to escape as a gas. To be perfectly safe, drain the cooking water.[...]

http://www.npr.org/templates/story/story.php?storyId=11861532

[1] http://www.atsdr.cdc.gov/toxprofiles/tp8-c1.pdf

Comment: Many frozen vegetables are precooked. Are you saying that's not the case with lima beans?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, I need to know whether frozen lima beans needs to be cooked or not?

Comment: Check what brand you have, most of the frozen beans I've used were raw. (YMMV)

Answer (score -1):

Frozen lima beans I have are in a state where you can slip the skin off and split in half. I think it is likely precooked

Comment: Have you ever tried it with fresh (not cooked, not dried, not frozen) lima beans? Same thing.